# How to store a mix of partial dates in PostgreSQL, which format can be yyyy-mm-dd, yyyy-mm or yyyy?

Tags: postgresql, date

How should I store a date in PostgreSQL when I have a mix of `yyyy-mm-dd` format (e.g., 2000-12-31), `yyyy-mm` and `yyyy` ? Can I still use a `DATE` column ?

Comment: yes you can use

Comment: Best option is to use a DATE column. If needed, you can preserve the precision in a second column, say an INT where 1 signifies "year", 2 signifies "year-month" and 3 signifies "year-month-day". That way you can tell the difference between "some time in 2020", "sometime in January of 2020" and "January 1st, 2020".

Comment: Look at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/269933/176905) question.

Answer (score 2):

The `to_date()` function can parse incomplete dates.  It will default the day to `01` if it is missing.  It will default by day and month to `01` if both are missing.  It will default the entire expression to `0001-01-01 BC` if you pass an empty string:

```
=# select to_date('2020', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
  to_date
------------
 2020-01-01
(1 row)

=# select to_date('2020-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
  to_date
------------
 2020-06-01
(1 row)

=# select to_date('2020-06-28', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
  to_date
------------
 2020-06-28
(1 row)

=# select to_date('', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
    to_date    
---------------
 0001-01-01 BC
(1 row)
```

Will these substitutions work for your use case?

**You indicated in your comment that this is not acceptable.**

There are three major advantages with date and time datatypes.

1. They use less space
2. They are validated by the engine
3. The engine provides all kinds of functions and operators for manipulating date and time values

People can provide ideas if you can please provide information on how you plan to use an invalid date value like `2020-00-00`.

Comment: The problem is that I also have entries with 1st January which are valid (verified). Dates like 2020-00-00 would be more acceptable.

Comment: @DevonDahon Can you please add a description of how you intend to use the incomplete data as an edit to your question, then?  For instance, how should these dates appear on reports or in a user interface?

Comment: Postgres will only accept valid date/datetimes in the date/timestamp fields, so ```2020-00-00``` will not work. If you want to do that then you will need to store as string.